# How to create a link that displays the page in your website instead of routing to the URL link?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Lets say hypothetically I want to display in my website a page from another website(Twitter/Instagram/ect..). Is there any possible way where I could.... Click the link and display the content in my own website page without having to redirect to Twitter/Instagram/google ect... Like maybe in a popup modal or something without having to open another browser window? If any one knows if this is possible please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You could try opening it in an iframe, but many sites will stop you from doing that.

Comment: Awesome this is the right answer. The other web page I need to link to is my own so I dont need to worry. Thanks!

Comment: You could do it using iframes and embed for twitter, linkedin, stackoverflow, youtube videos/playlist. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp I did it for twitter, Checkout this https://bitsnqubits.com